# WPF DataGrid bind to custom class

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I think the solution should be pretty straight forward. What I am trying to accomplish is to just display data contained in my generic List of custom type. I am just trying to display the data, I will not need to do any kind of data manipulation, and I would be interested in the simplest solution possible. The first grid works just fine, it displays the data, however, I am just not able to populate the second one. Would you be able to point me the right direction. Couldn't find anything similar online. Thanks

Here are my two data grids:

```
    <DataGrid x:Name="grdMyData" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="78,78,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="94" Width="321"/>

    <DataGrid x:Name="grdMyData2" ItemsSource="{Binding XPath=Car}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="101" Margin="78,198,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="321">       
    </DataGrid>
```

And code behind:

```
    private List<Car> myCars = new List<Car>();
    private List<Vehicle> myVehicles = new List<Vehicle>();

    private class Vehicle
    {
        public Car MyCar { get; set; }
    }

    private class Car
    {
        public string Type { get; set; }
        public string Color { get; set; }
        public int DoorsNo { get; set; }
    }

    private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var car1 = new Car(){Type = "hatchback", Color = "blue", DoorsNo = 5};
        var car2 = new Car() { Type = "sedan", Color = "red", DoorsNo = 4 };
        var car3 = new Car() { Type = "sedan", Color = "blach", DoorsNo = 4 };

        myCars.Add(car1);
        myCars.Add(car2);
        myCars.Add(car3);

        grdMyData.ItemsSource = myCars;

        var vehicle1 = new Vehicle() {MyCar = car1};
        var vehicle2 = new Vehicle() {MyCar = car2};
        var vehicle3 = new Vehicle() {MyCar = car3};
        myVehicles.Add(vehicle1);
        myVehicles.Add(vehicle2);
        myVehicles.Add(vehicle3);

        grdMyData2.DataContext = myVehicles;
    }
```

Is this the simplest way to retrieve the List of Car, or perhaps there is a better option

```
    private List<Car> GetVehicleCars()
    {
        var vehicleCars = new List<Car>();

        foreach (Vehicle v in myVehicles)
        {
            vehicleCars.Add(v.MyCar);   
        }
        return vehicleCars;
    }



grdMyData2.ItemsSource = GetVehicleCars();
```

Comment: your first grid show the cars (myCars) but your grid your bind vehicles (myVehicles) but that is a collection (List) and it doesn't find car (Car) in List... what is that you want to show in second grid?

Comment: Pretty much everything from my List of 'vehicles'. Lets say I may have many different type of vehicles, 'Car' just happens to be one of them. In this specific case I would like to see exactly the same data that I see in the first grid. I hope you see my concern.

Comment: OK but then the relationship above suggests Vehicle 'has-a' Car and not exactly Car is type of vehicle. But to continue with your case you need to then select cars from all vehicles and then bind that as itemssource for second grid

Comment: How may I accomplish it, what would be the simplest way to retrieve a list of 'Car' objects from 'Vehicle' List, so I could assign it into  item source of my grid. This would be pretty useful piece of knowledge. I am still new to OOP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think this is what you want. Just copy and paste it in a WPF application.
I changed the code a bit, i think you will be able to understand it.

Please note that this is very very ugly code, and you should never write code like this. I give this ugly, unpleasant answer, to keep the code similar to what you wrote.

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <DataGrid Grid.Row ="0" x:Name="grdMyData" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
    <DataGrid Grid.Row ="1" x:Name="grdMyData2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"></DataGrid>
    <Button Grid.Row="2" Click="ButtonBase_OnClick">PRESS ME</Button>
</Grid>
```

And the code behind:

```
namespace WpfApplication1
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        //private List<Car> myCars = new List<Car>();
        private List<Vehicle> myVehicles = new List<Vehicle>();

        private class Vehicle
        {
            public Car MyCar { get; set; }
        }

        private abstract class Car
        {
            public string Type { get; set; }
            public string Color { get; set; }
            public int DoorsNo { get; set; }
        }

        private class SimpleCar : Car { }
        private class FancyCar : Car { }

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void ButtonBase_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var car1 = new SimpleCar() { Type = "hatchback", Color = "blue", DoorsNo = 5 };
            var car2 = new SimpleCar() { Type = "sedan", Color = "red", DoorsNo = 4 };
            var car3 = new SimpleCar() { Type = "sedan", Color = "blach", DoorsNo = 4 };

            var car4 = new FancyCar() { Type = "fancy", Color = "white", DoorsNo = 3 };
            var car5 = new FancyCar() { Type = "veryFancy", Color = "yellow", DoorsNo = 3 };

            //myCars.Add(car1);
            //myCars.Add(car2);
            //myCars.Add(car3);

            var vehicle1 = new Vehicle() { MyCar = car1 };
            var vehicle2 = new Vehicle() { MyCar = car2 };
            var vehicle3 = new Vehicle() { MyCar = car3 };

            var vehicle4 = new Vehicle(){MyCar = car4};
            var vehicle5 = new Vehicle(){MyCar = car5};

            myVehicles.Add(vehicle1);
            myVehicles.Add(vehicle2);
            myVehicles.Add(vehicle3);
            myVehicles.Add(vehicle4);
            myVehicles.Add(vehicle5);


            var onlySimpleCars = from vehicle in myVehicles
                                  where (vehicle.MyCar.GetType() == typeof(SimpleCar))
                                  select vehicle.MyCar;

            var allCars = from vehicle in myVehicles
                              select vehicle.MyCar;

            grdMyData.ItemsSource = onlySimpleCars.ToList();
            grdMyData2.ItemsSource = allCars.ToList();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Jumast. This is exactly what I was after, this is great solution. Why are you saying this is ugly code, in my point of view it is very clean, and I think it fallows OOP rules. Since you answered fully the question, I will mark as answered, however, would you be able to elaborate what you personally dont like in the code structure above, and how would you achieve it differently. Appreciate the input, still learning

Comment: Hello Mauro (i'm guessing that's your name), i'm glad i could help you. I'm really sorry if my comment about the code was too rude. After reading it again it seemed pretty arrogant. I guess all i wanted to say, since you mentioned you were new to OOP, is that you should (as we all do) keep improving your design skills.Im not (not even close) an OOP expert, i'm fairly new to OOP as well.
So instead of me telling you what i dont like about the code, let me just suggest some things and ask a couple of questions. They may make you think a little.

Comment: 1) You could give you variables and methods more descriptive names, so the code is easier to understand and maintain (grdMyData and Button_Click_1, not very intention revealing)
2) Why are your classes private?
3) The Button_Click_1 method is too long (not a bad thing per se) and hard to understand, and its doing too many things. You could brake it into smaller, clearer, better named methods.
4) Your example is written in such a way that you cant really say if the code is doing what you want. You cant really test it, since both grids will always have the same content.

Comment: 5) Why do all you classes have parameterless constructors?
6) What happens if you change some property of a car through code, would the UI reflect that change?
7) Why did you design your Vehicle class like you did? It has a member of type Car. Does that make sense?
8) Do you think it's a good idea to put all that code in the code behind? Do you know any technique than would let you separate the UI from the logic in your model? Do you know what MVVM is?
9) Do you know what linq is?
10) Do you know what interfaces are and hoy to work with them?

...

Bye! Keep coding!

Comment: Thanks for the input, appreciate it ... happy coding